# Difficult hexagon chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, chemfig, tikz-shape, tikz-chains

I’m trying to draw this path graph of hexagons but it is disconnected beginning at a certain hexagon and then continues to the next.

I know how to create the hexagon path graph and have created disconnected ones, but I’m unsure as to how to add the dotted line to the graph and label the vertices considering I have only been able to create a chain going vertically then rotating 90 degrees (or I’d have to rotate each hexagon so that the edges can line up instead of the vertices).

Does anyone have insight as to how I’d create this with the dotted line and the disconnected hexagons? After reading something on shapes in latex using using tikz I’m still very unsure as to how to create these. The photo is of the chain created on word document.

Thank you very much for any help

[image: Photo created of the disconnected chain]

Comment: Welcome! I suggest that you show your (minimal) code to produce the hexagons and whatever more you have. That way, it will become more clear what, exactly, you need.

Comment: Please give feedback why none of the answer were accepted by you. What is missing from these answers?

Comment: I’m new to this site; I don’t know how to interact with comments. Do I reply to accept or click the check mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a 'repetitive' picture, let's repeat things with a `\foreach` loop. First place some coordinates and then draw the lines, the circles (vertices) and the labels.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1.5]
% coordinates
\foreach\i in {0,...,12}
{
  \coordinate (A\i) at ({0.5*sqrt(3)*\i},{1+0.5*mod(\i,2)}); % top
  \coordinate (B\i) at ({0.5*sqrt(3)*\i}, {-0.5*mod(\i,2)}); % bottom
}
% left hexagons
\draw (A6) foreach\i in {6,...,0} {-- (A\i)} -- (B0) foreach\i in {1,...,6} {-- (B\i)};
\foreach\i in {2,4,6}
  \draw (A\i) -- (B\i);
% right hexagon
\draw (A10) -- (A11) -- (A12) -- (B12) -- (B11) -- (B10) -- cycle;
% dashed lines
\foreach\i in {A,B}\foreach\j in {6,9}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\k{\j+1}
  \draw[gray,dotted] (\i\j) -- (\i\k);
\draw  [gray,dotted] (A7)   ++ (0.2,-1) --++ ({sqrt(3)-0.4},0);
% vertices and labels
\foreach\i in {0,...,7,9,10,11,12}
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
  \draw[fill=white] (A\i) circle (0.4mm) \ifnum\i<3 node[above] {$\j$}\fi;
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{6-\i}
  \draw[fill=white] (B\i) circle (0.4mm) \ifnum\i<3 node[below] {$\j$}\fi;
}
\node[yshift=5mm]    at (A10) {$2n-3$};
\node[above]         at (A11) {$2n-4$};
\node[above right]   at (A12) {$2n+1$};
\node[below right]   at (B12) {$2n$};
\node[below]         at (B11) {$2n-1$};
\node[yshift=-5mm]   at (B10) {$2n-2$};
\foreach\i in {1,2,3}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{2*\i-1}
  \node[yshift=-1cm] at (B\j) {\Large$H_\i$};
\node[yshift=-1cm]   at (B7)  {\Large$\cdots$};
\node[yshift=-1cm]   at (B9)  {\Large$\cdots$};
\node[yshift=-1cm]   at (B11) {\Large$H_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

with `chemfig` package

```
\documentclass[border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\atsep{4em}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[atom sep=\atsep]{
        *6(--(*6(--(*6(--(*6(--[,,,,draw=none](*6(-[,,,,draw=none]-(*6(-----))---[,,,,draw=none]))-[,,,,draw=none]-[,,,,draw=none]-))---))---))----)
    }
    \chemmove{
        \coordinate (R1) at (cyclecenter1);
        \coordinate (R2) at (cyclecenter2);
        \coordinate (R3) at (cyclecenter3);
        \coordinate (R4) at (cyclecenter4);
        \coordinate (R5) at (cyclecenter5);
        \coordinate (R6) at (cyclecenter6);
        \draw[-, dashed, shorten <=10pt, shorten >=10pt] (R4) -- (R5);
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3,6}{\foreach \y in {30,90,...,330}{
            \draw[fill=white] (R\x) ++(\y:\atsep) circle[radius=2pt];}}
        \foreach \x in {4,5}{\foreach \y in {90,270}{
                \draw[fill=white] (R\x) ++(\y:\atsep) circle[radius=2pt];}}
        \path[every node/.style={circle, label distance=-0.5em}]
            (R1) ++(150:\atsep) node[label={150:1}] {}
            (R1) ++(90:\atsep) node[label={90:2}] {}
            (R1) ++(30:\atsep) node[label={90:3}] {}
            (R1) ++(-30:\atsep) node[label={270:4}] {}
            (R1) ++(-90:\atsep) node[label={-90:5}] {}
            (R1) ++(-150:\atsep) node[label={-150:6}] {}
            (R1) ++(-90:3em+\atsep) node {$\mathrm{H}_1$}
            (R2) ++(-90:3em+\atsep) node {$\mathrm{H}_2$}
            (R6) ++(-90:3em+\atsep) node {$\mathrm{H}_n$};
        \path[every node/.style={label distance=-0.5em}]
            (R6) ++(30:\atsep) node[label={30:$2n+1$}] {}
            (R6) ++(90:\atsep) node[label={90:$2n-4$}] {}
            (R6) ++(150:\atsep) node[label={[label distance=0.3em]90:$2n-3$}] {}
            (R6) ++(-150:\atsep) node[label={[label distance=0.3em]-90:$2n-2$}] {}
            (R6) ++(-90:\atsep) node[label={-90:$2n-1$}] {}
            (R6) ++(-30:\atsep) node[label={-30:$2n$}] {};
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `regular polygons` and their anchors as references.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape border rotate=30, draw, minimum size=3cm, outer sep=0pt}]

    \node[hexagon, label={[label distance=5mm]below:$H_1$}] (h1) {};
    \node[hexagon, label={[label distance=5mm]below:$H_2$}, right=-.25\pgflinewidth of h1.side 5] (h2) {};
    \node[hexagon, label={[label distance=5mm]below:$H_3$}, right=-.25\pgflinewidth of h2.side 5] (h3) {};
    \node[hexagon, right=-.25\pgflinewidth of h3.side 5, draw=none] (h4) {};
    \node[hexagon, right=-.25\pgflinewidth of h4.side 5, draw=none] (h5) {};
    \node[hexagon, label={[label distance=5mm]below:$H_n$}, right=-.25\pgflinewidth of h5.side 5] (h6) {};
    \draw[dotted] (h4.corner 2)--(h4.corner 1);
    \draw[dotted] (h4.corner 3)--(h4.corner 4);
    \draw[dotted] (h5.corner 1)--(h5.corner 6);
    \draw[dotted] (h5.corner 4)--(h5.corner 5);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
        \foreach \j in {1,2,3,6}
            \draw[fill=white] (h\j.corner \i) circle (2pt);
    \foreach \i/\j in {4/1, 4/4, 5/1, 5/4}
        \draw[fill=white] (h\i.corner \j) circle(2pt);
    \foreach \i in {-5pt, 0pt, 5pt}
        \draw[fill] ([xshift=\i]h4.side 5) circle(1pt);
    \foreach \i/\j in {1/2,2/1,3/6}
        \node[above=1mm] at (h1.corner \j) {\i};
    \foreach \i/\j in {$2n-3$/2,$2n-4$/1,$2n+1$/6}
        \node[above=1mm] at (h6.corner \j) {\i};
    \foreach \i/\j in {4/5,5/4,6/3}
        \node[below=1mm] at (h1.corner \j) {\i};
    \foreach \i/\j in {$2n$/5,$2n-1$/4,$2n-2$/3}
        \node[below=1mm] at (h6.corner \j) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]